# Weather widget on Big Sur

Tags: notifications, widgets

The weather widget on Big Sur is a step down from the previous one, to put it lightly.

Is there any way to add multiple cities to a single widget, or to actually have the widget point to a working web page when clicking on it? On the old system I used to have one widget, and I could switch between the cities, showing both the daily and weekly weather forecast for the selected city. Now, I have to either have four huge widgets which take up way too much place, or use smaller widgets, at the cost of having no forecast. As if it weren't enough, when clicking on a widget, I am taken to a web page which simply says
"**Oops! We are having trouble finding your page.**"

Anyway, my question is - could anyone recommend a working widget substitute for weather, preferably one that shows weekly forecast and allows multiple cities. Is it even possible to install third party widgets?